# PDO_MYSQL is not available from Apache

Tags: php, apache, centos7

After compiling php 5.3.28 on CentOS 7 I saw that pdo_mysql is missed and I need to make another compile  with pdo_mysql.

After the second compile, pdo_mysql is only available when I am executing php script from command line not from Apache.

I tried to enable the pdo_mysql.so extension in php.ini but nothing changed.

Do you know how to make pdo_mysql to be enabled when I am executing php scripts over apache (Apache 2.4.6)?

Comment: Why are you compiling it? Remi has a [CentOS 7 repo](http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en) you can use with everything compiled for you. 5.3 is well into EOL

Comment: @Machavity, actually my point is to install php5.3.28 with libxml2-2.9.1, and I red from other articles that libxml2-2.9.1 is only available on CentOS 7. When I installed CentOS 7 I tried to compile php5.3.28 because that php version wasn't available form the Remi repository. Any suggestions?

Comment: Like I said, [5.3 is in End Of Life](http://php.net/eol.php). Remi offers 5.4 and later. I would strongly urge you to upgrade.

Comment: @Machavity, my issue is for reproducing a bug in my php application not for placing environment in production. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

If this is a box for testing, I would suggest the following.

First, build CentOS 6. There's a LOT more support out there for that as opposed to 7.

Second, you CAN install libxml2 2.9.1 on EL6. It's just not an [official build](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/23647988/dir/redhat_el_6/com/libxml2-2-2.9.1-2.1.x86_64.rpm.html)

Third, I would look into [Atomic Nucleus](https://www.atomicorp.com/wiki/index.php/Nucleus) and see if they'd let you install it for free. It's a 5.3 repo and should have what you need.

Comment: I cannot install the libxml2 rpm package on CentOS 6.5. When I am executing `rpm -Uvh libxml2.rpm`, the output says the package is 100% installed but when I am checking if the package is installed with `rpm -q` the old libxml version is displayed.

Comment: You might need to dig around in Google. Core packages can often be found off the beaten path